# Should I use navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have an app in which I would like a slide out menu.  It would not be in control of all the apps settings, just a simple menu with a few options.  I will still have a settings menu so I don't want to get rid of that. I would like to activate the slide menu with an icon in one of the corners of the app.  On the button click I would like to slide out this simple menu (not settings).

Should I use the Navigation Drawer?  My first thought is no since I am not controlling any sort of navigation from within this slider.  Navigation Drawer also has some default behaviors that I am not sure you can override, i.e. slide from left side of screen to access, click app icon to access, click settings menu to access.

Am I supposed to use a Navigation Drawer and try and override a bunch of behavior or is there another android pattern that I can use?

Comment: You're right, there are behaviors like left-to-right that you can't override (without implementing it yourself). What are the options? Do you know you could use an action button and display a dialog box or submenu? (This question should be in UX.StackExchange)

Comment: Thanks @StevenTrigg!  Possible to slide out a sub menu out of the box or do I need to implement something custom or pull in an external library?

Comment: My mistake, you can configure it to pull right-to-left. Just not up or down.

Comment: Even with left-right or right-left still wondering if using the Navigation Drawer for a 'sub-menu' ie not navigation at all, just selecting some specific options is the right approach.  If others have used this the Nav Drawer for sub menus I would like to know to get the slide effect I would love to know.

Comment: Adding UI components like Navigation Drawer shouldn't be thought because it would look cool for users. You must think it like why would you use a Navigation Drawer UI pattern. For example if you have only two top views you can instead you "ActionBar Spinner" and for sub views you can have "Tabs" or "PagerTitleStrip". Also menu shouldn't be used as navigation itself.